# Why DataTable TableTools export to pdf or excel or csv is not working with Private Browser?

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I am working with [**TableTools**](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/api),which is a plug-in for the **[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)** HTML table enhancer, which adds a highly customisable button toolbar to a DataTable. Key features include:

- Copy to clipboard
- Save table data as CSV, XLS or PDF files
- Print view for clean printing
- Row selection options
- Easy use predefined buttons
- Simple customisation of buttons
- Well defined API for advanced control

which is a quick adaptable and codable flash based plugin.This is working fine for me.

Even I here tried all possible export ways and fulfilling all the requirements of mine.

> The Issue what i am facing here is this export to file.x is not working to me in Private browser(**incognito**) instances, it is not able to save the file at the destination.

For quick reference you can try [**this**](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) example .

Can any one suggest me how to achieve this,if it is not possible what is the reason behind it?

1. **My Sample Page Reference.**

[image]

2. **Copy & Print view is working.**

[image]
[image]

3. **Even it is prompting to show destination path for saving , but it is not saving.**

[image]

Any Suggestion will be highly appreciable Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have probably disabled flash so it not works automatically.

Comment: @davidkonrad if that is the case then i should not able to see buttons at all .

Comment: Why do you think that? It is not flash that is generating the buttons, it is tableTools. Why not check the suggestion out instead of debating it? This has been the case for tabletools ever since some browsers started to disable flash by default.

Comment: @davidkonrad I thought buttons are flash content ,to confirm things i just commented that, i enabled all extensions that i have in chrome to incognito but no use.Please Check the images what i placed in post .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug in Chrome; I can replicate it in Chromium 49, even though the Flash download still works in Firefox or IE11. Considering it is a Chrome bug it might be hard to fix without deeper knowledge of Chrome and (Pepper) Flash, follow the Issue on the [Chromium bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=567748).

I would consider switching to the Buttons extension (that means upgrading to DataTables 1.10) and use [HTML5 Export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) which will work with Chrome. For reference, the DataTable 1.10 version also can't save through flash on Chrome.

Comment: I never thought in this way , I was suspecting DataTable plugin, But thanks a lot for directing me in proper  direction